# Nested binding to observable collection not working in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

With a page I have the following table

```
        <table>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: myfilters">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="with: $root.iqReports">
                        <select data-bind="options: SelectedAttributes(), optionsText: function(SelectedAttributes){ return SelectedAttributes.NameHierarchy() + '.' + SelectedAttributes.LabelName() },  optionsCaption:'Select a Field...'"></select>  
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select data-bind="options: $root.filterOperators, value:operator, optionsText: 'operatorName'">
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input data-bind="value: criteria1" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input data-bind="value: criteria2" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select data-bind="options: $root.joinOperators, value:joinOperator, optionsText: 'joinName'">
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a class="attributeLink" data-bind="click: $root.removeFilter">Remove</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

The collection my filters populates the necessary elements correctly. Where I am struggling is with the first cell where I am trying to populate a select element using another observable collection (iqReports). When I run the page firebug does not report any errors but the  element is empty.

HTML from Firebug:

```
<td data-bind="with: $root.iqReports"></td>
```

I realize something is wrong with attempting to bind in this fashion because moving the select element outside of the  works fine.

Can anyone provide some insight as to how to setup this type of binding?

Update: Here is a partial fiddle that shows the markup used in creation of the filters and report object http://jsfiddle.net/rlcrews/e7z93/

-cheers

Comment: can you make a fiddle ?

Comment: can you please provide an example of the iqReports object?

Comment: @Jalayn updated with partial fiddle

Comment: @rlcrews I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve, but check out kadumel's answer. In your HTML, it shouls be "iqReport", not "iqReports", but other than that... it seems to work as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see an iqReports object or observable in your view model only an iqReport.  Change your html to reflect an iqReport and see if that tidies it up I can't tell from your fiddle...

And for the record when I am cascading dropdowns in Knockout I make the second list an observable based on the first -

```
var self.firstList = ko.observableArray(objects);
var self.firstListSelected = ko.observable(null);

var self.secondList = ko.computed(function () {
    var list = ko.observableArray();
    if (self.firstListSelected() == null) { return list(null); }
    list(getDependentObjectsSomehow());
}
```

Comment: ugh nothing like a good ol typo. Thanks for catching that and thanks for the tip on cascading dropdowns

Comment: No problem, also I updates the suggestion to correctly cast the observables so it makes more sense.